# Google Script: "EMAIL_SENT" value not set in desired column despite email being sent successfully using MailApp.sendEmail

Tags: email, timestamp, send

I was wondering if you could please help. I am trying to use the MailApp.sendEmail method to send emails when a date is entered into column M. I currently use a button on the spreadsheet to trigger the sending of emails and this works fine: emails are sent.

I naturally wish for duplicate emails not to be sent and as such I wish for the "EMAIL_SENT" value to entered into Column N at the moment I trigger the sending of emails, but this does not work. This is despite my code pretty much replicating what is shown on google's own page (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/sending_emails) *et al*.

I also wish it to generate a timestamp into Column O when emails are sent. Again, this does not work, but I can believe my approach is not correct. I'll be honest and say I am new to this!

Please advise me on where the errors are in my code.

```
var EMAIL_SENT = "EMAIL_SENT";

function SEWEmailReminder() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var numRows = sheet.getLastRow(); // nothing to change
var startRow = "9"; // put the row number where the formula should start
var range = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 22) // Fetch the range of cells A9:Vx
var data = range.getValues();

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
var row = data[i]; 
var programmeid = row[0];              // 1st column A
var programmename = row[1];            // 2nd column B
var author = row[2];                   // 3rd column C
var authoremail = row[3];              // 4th column D
var comments = row[4];                 // 5th column E
var programmestatus = row[5];          // 6th column F
var datadate = row[6];                 // 7th column G
var plannedcompletiondate = row[7];    // 8th column H
var completiondate = row[8];           // 9th column I
var presubjointreviewdate = row[9];    // 10th column J
var plannedsubdate = row[10];          // 11th column K
var jvissuedate = row[11];             // 12th column L
var sewresponsedate = row[12];         // 13th column M
var emailsent = row[13];               // 14th column N
var emailtimestamp = row[14];          // 15th column O
var sewreviewdate = row[15];           // 16th column P
var jvreceiveddate = row[16];          // 17th column Q
var difference = row[17];              // 18th column R
var rejectedaccepted = row[18];        // 19th column S
var recipients = row[19];              // 20th column T
var forclientacceptance = row[20];     // 21st column U
var jvreceiveddate = row[21];          // 22nd column V
var subject = "SEW Notification Email";
var message = "Dear " + author + ",\nYou have received this email to notify you that the SEW Response Date is " + sewresponsedate + " for Programme ID " + programmeid + ", titled " + programmename + ".\nKind Regards,\nAdmin"
if (row[12] != "") {
    if (emailsent != EMAIL_SENT) {  // Prevents sending duplicates
    MailApp.sendEmail(authoremail, subject, message);
    sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 14).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
    sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 15).setValue(new Date()); // set date & time stamp
    // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  }  
}
}
}
```